# Fixed points of a dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

My understanding was that a fixed point of a dynamical system $\dot{x} = f(x)$ is a point $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$ and that if an (autonomous) system starts in a fixed point it will stay there.

But for instance the system defined by $\dot{x} = 2x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ with initial condition $x(0) = 0$ has as a solution $x(t) = t^{2}$, which definitely does not stay at 0, although $2x^{\frac{1}{2}} = 0$ when $x = 0$. so where is my thinking going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Staying at the fixed point is surely one possible solution of the ODE. But to conclude that the system *must* stay at the fixed point, you need to know that the solution is *unique*. (The standard sufficient condition for this is that the right-hand side is a Lipschitz continuous function of $x$; see [the Picard–Lindelöf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).)

Your example is a classical example of an ODE with non-unique solution. (The right-hand side $2 \sqrt{x}$ is not Lipschitz at $x=0$.)